# Firefox Not Prompting to Allow Microphone Gmail > Make a Call

Tags: sound, kubuntu, firefox, pulseaudio, microphone

I'm running Kubuntu 19.10 (fully updated) and Firefox 75.

Gmail allows you to make phone calls if you have a [Google Voice](https://voice.google.com/) account.

Prior to yesterday, each time I'd make a call, Firefox would prompt me, asking if I wanted to allow my microphone to be shared during the call.

Now, not only does Firefox not prompt me, if I click the lock-icon, it doesn't seem to realize that the phone call requires microphone sharing:
[image]

In the above screenshot, I've initiated a call, and I see no way to share my mic. This results in me being able to hear the other person, but they cannot hear me.

If I try the same thing in Chromium it works, and before yesterday, it worked in Firefox.

How can I get Firefox to prompt me for microphone sharing again?

Comment: I reviewed [documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-manage-your-camera-and-microphone-permissions) for sharing the Microphone, but Firefox doesn't allow you to add microphone sharing to a site that doesn't ask for it. The issue seems to be that Firefox isn't even realizing the microphone is needed.

Comment: Would check firefox permissions page and see microphone settings, maybe they changed, also check other permissions.

Comment: I completely deleted my .mozilla folder, making all setting "fresh install" settings and the problem still persists. [Perhaps google has changed something server-side](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138918/)?

Comment: But did you check what the settings are?  You might need to change them, defaults might be the problem.

Comment: @crip659 : Indeed I [did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QATz.png). Firefox acts as though no website has ever prompted for the microphone's use; searches for `google` or `gmail`, for example come up empty [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QATz.png).

Comment: Check settings for pop ups and notifications and tracking also.  Try with them open up, also try with extensions disabled.  Checking gmail settings might show something.

Comment: @crip659 I've checked all of that stuff. Firefox still doesn't realize that the mic is needed to facilitate the call.

Comment: Some googling found a similar problem fixed with a clean install and restart(maybe windows).  Link  https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/c7tyqf/firefox_microphone_not_working/

Comment: This problem went away yesterday evening. I assume a routine update modified a package that was causing this issue, or maybe a Google employee saw [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138918/) and fixed something on the server-side. I'm not sure, but what I am sure about it that is stopped working for almost a week straight and then started working again yesterday.

Comment: This problem is back for me in Firefox 75.